# I have a bitmap and a shape is drawn over it. Now I rotate and bitmap and want the shape to be rotated as well. How to get the point of a shape?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, rotation

I want to make a custom image cropper for Android that supports rotation. Cropper works fine. The problem that i am facing while rotating the image (bitmap of the using using rotation matrix) the crop overlay area should also be rotated accordingly. For that I rotated the points of the crop shape by applying another rotation matrix. It map the points of the crop shape (specifically the bounding box pointed by different color circle in the image). The rotation matrix is applied for crop shape rotating is applied with the center of the crop shape as origin. But after rotating the crop shape the points of the shape should be translated to maintain the same position and aspect ratio. Can any one help me please to achieve this? [image: Original Image with crop shape over it] [[image: Rotated image that i am getting...Look the crop shape is not in the expected position although it is rotated with respect to it's center point2][image: The actual position of the crop area that i am expecting. Note that as image bitmap width and height is changed the crop shape width height should also change. I guess it just need to translate the position of the points. So I need a way to calculate the updated position of the point] I am sharing some code snippet to rotate the bitmap and crop shape points

```
private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    rotateShapePoints(angle);
    return rotatedBitmap;
}
```

Rotate Shape Points

```
 private void rotateShapePoints(float angle)
{
    PointF centerPoint = getCropShapeView().getCenterPoint(); // return the center of the shape
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle,centerPoint.x,centerPoint.y);
    HashMap<Integer,PointF> points = (HashMap<Integer, PointF>) getCropShapeView().getPoints(); // map is used to track the point at different position
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,PointF> entry : points.entrySet())
    {
        int key = entry.getKey();
        PointF value = entry.getValue();
        float[] pointArray = new float[] { value.x,value.y};
        matrix.mapPoints(pointArray);
        PointF rotatedPoint = new PointF(Math.abs(pointArray[0]),Math.abs(pointArray[1]));
        points.put(key,rotatedPoint);
    }
    getCropShapeView().setPoints(points);
    getCropShapeView().invalidate();
}
```